# Set cookie in subdomain and use it in domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I searched for many questions in the forum about setting cookies across domains and subdomains but I don't find this exact scenario. I've created a cookie in my subdomain `sub1.example.com` and my configuration is something like:

`var cookieDomain = ".example.com";`

When I visit any other subdomain it works fine and the cookie is set all around. The problem is in the main website `www.example.com`, it doesn't work at all and can't read the cookie.

How can I set a cookie in a subdomain and use it in main domain?

Comment: Check the ‘https only’ parameter of your cookie

Comment: @MiladElyasi so something like `document.cookie = cookieName;expirationTime;cookiePath;cookieDomain;secure;HttpOnly";` should work fine??

Comment: the point is that your cookie should not be https only true! Set it false!

Comment: @MiladElyasi it does not work for me. I've configured SameSite, secure and HttpOnly parameters to (None, Strict, Lax) and (false, true) to test all options... but nothing works. When I fill cookie value in my `sub1.example.com` I can see it in `sub2.example.com` but not in `example.com` main site.

Comment: try `www.example.com' (with www.)

Comment: @MiladElyasi if I use `var cookieDomain = "www.example.com"` it doesn't work through `sub1.example.com` or `sub2.example.com`

Comment: no, try to check giving cookie in "www.example.com". do not use the address via www for cookie domain! 
`var cookieDomain = ".example.com"`

try to visit  "www.example.com" instead of " "example.com" to check the cookie. if it was set on it, you may redirect all your address with www